# to make a handle event that handles a toggle button responsible for adding or removing permissions from a role while creating or editing a role

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

I have a phoenix live component that adds and edits new roles, the component also has toggles for adding and removing permissions from a role while editing or creating a role

I tried using permission ids to populate or depopulating an existing list of roles while editing or creating a role

Comment: A small code example outlining the described component would be helpful to understand the exact problem.